# Редактирование *.apk

Tags: java, android, отладка, reverse-engineering, дизассемблирование

Есть IDE для smali, с подсветкой синтаксиса и поиском ошибок, и чтобы обеспечивала деассемблирование/сборку 1 кликом и т.д.?

В идеале бы так:

1. Файл -> Открыть проект -> apk
2. В Package Explorer получаем дерево классов
3. Нужные классы открываем в многовкладочном интерфейсе, редактируем
4. Сохраняем -> apk

Answer (score 2):

[Virtuous Ten Studio](http://virtuous-ten-studio.com/), как один из вариантов, наиболее близкий к вашему желанию.